# How can I display the content of user profile using the Views module?

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a view for displaying the title of the content posted by the user whose profile is being currently shown using the Views module. I am using the following modules:

- Views for displaying the profile related content
- Panels: for displaying the user profile

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow what a coincidence this question was posted for drupal 6 just this morning.

To list content owned by a user you can:

1. Create a View that lists content
2. Create a Block Display within that view
3. Configure a "Contextual filter" for "Content: Author UID" and set its "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" setting to "Provide a default value", then select "User ID from URL" for the "Type".
4. Place that block on the user profile page using some mechanism for Block placement, like the drupal core block system or the context or panels modules.